# How posting One Signal notification's additional data and receiving that?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, onesignal

I checked OneSignal documentation but I couldn't understand clearly as beginner how setting dictionary as a post notification's additional data (like postID, userID, type) in iOS Native SDK using Swift to decide and redirect when user interacted with notification.

For posting I'm doing only like that:

```
 OneSignal.sendTag("username", value: "\(user)")
 OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "@\(user) added an additive to your '\(title)' experience: \"\(strLast)\""],
                                                                "include_player_ids": [postOwnerPlayerID],
```

For receiving:

```
 OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "______", handleNotificationReceived: nil, handleNotificationAction: {
        (result) in

        // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
        let payload = result?.notification.payload

        //Try to fetch the action selected
        if let additionalData = payload?.additionalData {

            print("payload")
            print(additionalData)
        }

        // After deciding which action then I can redirect user..

        let username: String? = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: KEY_UID)

        if username != nil {

            if let tabbarController = self.window!.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                tabbarController.selectedViewController = tabbarController.viewControllers?[2]
                // NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Foundation.Notification.Name(rawValue: "notificationsUp"), object: nil)
            }
        }

    }, settings: [kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption : OSNotificationDisplayType.none.rawValue])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You set the `data` field as a key in the dictionary passed to `OneSignal.postNotification` like the following.

```
OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "Test Message"],
                            "include_player_ids": ["3009e210-3166-11e5-bc1b-db44eb02b120"],
                            "data": ["postID": "id"]])
```

Then you need to get ready your keys from `additionalData` from the `payload` in the `handleNotificationAction` function.

```
if let additionalData = payload?.additionalData {
   let postID: String? = additionalData["postID"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me!

Answer (score 4):

Example from iOS in objC to send additional data...

```
[OneSignal postNotification:@{@"contents":@{@"en":text},
                              @"include_player_ids":oneSignalIds,
                              @"data":@{@"key": @"value"},
                              }];
```

And to receive the data...

```
 [OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                           appId:ONESIGNAL_APPID
      handleNotificationReceived:^(OSNotification *notification) {

          if (notification.payload.additionalData) {

              NSDictionary* additionalData = notification.payload.additionalData;

              if (additionalData[@"key"]){
                  NSLog(@"Received Data - %@", additionalData[@"key"]);
              }
          }
      }

        handleNotificationAction:nil
                        settings:@{kOSSettingsKeyInAppAlerts:@YES}];
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jkasten helped me in the right direction! helped me get rid of the `AnyHashable` warning I was getting.

**Swift 3 code** (change PATH to the additionalData parameter you want to output):

```
let PATH = notification!.payload.additionalData["PATH"]
print("PATH: ",PATH as Any)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do the same but in the Notification Service Extension, take a look at our [updated documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#section-getting-a-payload-from-a-notification-span-class-label-all-label-ios-ios-span-).

The Notification Service Extension is used for:
- Badges
- Influenced Opens with Firebase Analytics
- Media Attachments
- Action Buttons