# how to get additional data sent from one signal console in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, push-notification, onesignal

I know that maybe similar thread has been asked in here [How posting One Signal notification's additional data and receiving that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634759/how-posting-one-signal-notifications-additional-data-and-receiving-that) , but as a beginner I am confused how to implement the answer.

so, I try to send push notification through one signal console. and I need to send custom data in order to navigate the user to certain view controller after the user tap the push notification like this

[image]

but unfortunately I don't know how to get that key value pairs of that `destination` and `idItem`. I assume I have to do something on my AppDelegate , but I don't know how to get that key value pairs when the user interact with the push notification sent.

from that thread, I get

```
let PATH = notification!.payload.additionalData["PATH"]
print("PATH: ",PATH as Any)
```

but.... I don't know where to implement this code

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the answer. in `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "YOUR ONE SIGNAL APP ID HERE", handleNotificationAction: { (result) in

            let payload = result?.notification.payload
            if let additionalData = payload?.additionalData {

                let destination = additionalData["destination"] as? String ?? ""
                print("the destination is: \(destination)")

            }


        },settings: onesignalInitSettings)
```

Comment: What is "onesignalInitSettings"?